No se muestran los datos de mi BD
Que tal comunidad estoy trabajando en un proyecto de mi escuela para realizar un sitio web para la evaluacion de los empleados, dentro de este proyecto cree una base de datos para poder hacer pruebas ahorita me encuentro en una parte de mi proyecto en la que tengo que hacer esta consulta en mi base de datos y mostrarla dentro de una tabla HTML (select * from firmasFaltantes) les muestro mi html donde debo mostrarlo
 <tbody>
     @if ViewData("ReportList") IsNot "null" Then
     @For Each item In ViewData("ReportList")
     @<tr>
       <td>@item.nombre</td>
       <td>@item.puesto</td>
       <td>@item.fecha_de_ingreso.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
       <td>@item.calificacion</td>
       <td>@item.ultima_evaluacion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
       <td>@item.siguiente_evaluacion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
       <td>@item.vencimiento_de_evaluacion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
       <td>@item.status</td>
     </tr>
  Next
Else
  @<tr>
     <td> esto falla </td>
  </tr>
End If
</tbody> 

Tengo algunos proyectos para usar de referencia y el back end lo estoy haciendo con VB en modelo vista controlador se supone que debe jalar la informacion por medio del controlador que es quien hace la conexion con la bd y jala la informacion de la consulta pero a la hora de mostrarlo dentro de mi codigo html no entra en el for each si no que se va directo al ELSE entonces no se en que me estara fallando por que no me muestra nada en la consola ni siquiera algun warning por lo que recurro a este foro para saber si ustedes saben de algo mas que me falte (aparte de conocimiento gracias) para poder resolver este problema estoy un poco estresado ya que tengo varios dias aqui (dejo abajo el controlador para que puedan verlo tambien como se supone debe funcionar) gracias de ante mano.
        Dim MyConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PAMIntranet_DevConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim ReportList As New List(Of firmasFaltantes)()
        Using cnn As New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
            Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM firmasFaltantes"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(qry, cnn)
            cnn.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While reader.Read()
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Nombre: {reader("nombre")}, Puesto: {reader("puesto")}, fecha de ingreso: {reader("fecha_de_ingreso")}, calificacion: {reader("calificacion")}, Ultima Evaluacion: {reader("ultima_evaluacion")}, Siguiente Evaluacion: {reader("siguiente_evaluacion")}, Vencimiento de Evaluacion: {reader("vencimiento_de_evaluacion")}, Status: {reader("status")}")
                    ' Agrega más propiedades según la estructura de tu tabla firmasFaltantes
                End While
            End If
            While reader.Read()
                Dim firma As New firmasFaltantes()
                firma.nombre = reader.GetString(1)
                firma.puesto = reader.GetString(2)
                firma.fecha_de_ingreso = reader.GetDateTime(3)
                firma.calificacion = reader.GetFloat(4)
                firma.ultima_evaluacion = reader.GetDateTime(5)
                firma.siguiente_evaluacion = reader.GetDateTime(6)
                firma.vencimiento_de_evaluacion = reader.GetDateTime(7)
                firma.status = reader.GetString(8)
                ReportList.Add(firma)
            End While
            reader.Close()
        End Using
        Return View(ReportList)
    End Function ´´´


El problema es que esta recorriendo dos veces el reader, y en la primera vuelta ya lo consumiste todo, con lo cual lo segundo no va a funcionar... cada vez que haces read(), va al registro siguiente hasta que termina. O reseteas el reader, o no lo lees dos veces... entiendo que lo haces como control, pero eso es lo que hace que falle...
